# How to get the text from a control type : client using coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a Windows Application, which has a control type: Client and
class name =WindowsForms10.WIndows.8.app.0.3ce0bb8_r11_ad1

It is like a sub title bar. It has a text which displays the number of records in the table below. I want to extract that number of records. How ever when I spy using UIMap-CodedUI Test Builder, it highlight the entire title bar and does not only highlight the number of records. Is there any way I can handle this.[image]
I want to extract 495 from the title bar. How can I do that?

Comment: What software are you using to test your application?

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2012 to run Coded UI scripts

Comment: Try using the spy tool provided and go deeper into the control. If you move inside the title bar, you should be able to find the text control that has a Text or Value property containing the data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your reply.

I could figure out an answer.

1) 495 is not shown as a UI control.

2) I found a work around , I can calculate the rows in the table below using **UISyncDataGridTable.Rows.Count**

and it serves my purpose.

Comment: In this type of condition "Ctrl + i " is also possible way. More Info refer  link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456251(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You could use AutoHotkey. [This](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlGetText.htm) or [this](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinGet.htm) function should be able to complete the task you want. The installer also comes with windows spy, which might help you pinpoint the control class you want to extract the string from.

Comment: Do I need to install AutoHotKey on my Test Machine too?

Comment: Currently I am working on dev environment.How can I include it in my codedUI project?

Comment: There are a few ways you could do it. One would be using [postMessage or sendMessage](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm) from an AHK script or compiled script. You can also write and run AHK scripts dynamically from C#. I'm not an expert in C# or visual studio, but I know that it is possible.